# how to get WCF WS client to log requests and responses by app.config tracing?

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config, trace

My app.config is below. However there i nothing in C:\temp\xxx\ folder. What I'm missing? This is 1st time i ever try this so I don't know anything about this. There is nothing in code. I think something is tried to be done because if I have the response formatted (line feeds and tabs) the response results in exception. I use soapUI mock service to return response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\temp\xxx\App_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:\temp\xxx\App_messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My WS client is built to WSClient.dll which is used from MainProgram.exe. In build my App.config of the WSClient project was translated to WSClient.dll.config. I thought that this was ok. However it must be copied to MainProgram.exe.config and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks ok, please note you have to restart the service after adding logs. Make sure that the service has all required permissions for creating log files

here is my version of a config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="app_messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp, ThreadId">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add initializeData="app_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="false">
        <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
        <service name="Nelibur.ServiceModel.Services.JsonServicePerCall">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9095/feedback" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="Nelibur.ServiceModel.Contracts.IJsonService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: thanks. i created it with this editor thing. there "shouldn't b" permission issue but i try it again and read ur version when i hav more time.

Comment: so i emphasize that this is app.config of the client. it seems that i have Version=2.0.0.0 for some reason